# Need help combining two Xpaths

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to parse EVE market data from EVE Central (https://eve-central.com/home/develop.html) using xpath 1.0 and I've run into a wall.

The source data is here:

http://api.eve-central.com/api/quicklook?typeid=34

I'm trying to get the minimum sell order from station named 'Jita'. So I broke it down into two steps that both work but when combined they fail.

Xpath to get minimum sell order works fine and returns the lowest priced order:

```
$x("//quicklook/sell_orders/order[not(preceding-sibling::order/price <= price ) and not(following-sibling::order/price < price)] ")
```

Getting station named 'Jita' works and returns all sell orders from station name Jita:

```
$x("//quicklook/sell_orders/order [contains(./station_name, 'Jita')] ")
```

So what I want to do is combine the two and get the minimum sell order from station named 'Jita'. Logically (to my mind) would be two concatenate the two with an 'and' to get this order, like this...

```
$x("//quicklook/sell_orders/order [contains(./station_name, \'Jita\') and (not(preceding-sibling::order/price <= price ) and not(following-sibling::order/price < price))] ")
```

...but this results in empty array. This is my first stab at using xpath so I'm probably missing something simple. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression you need is `//quicklook/sell_orders/order [contains(station_name, 'Jita') and (not(preceding-sibling::order[contains(station_name, 'Jita')]/price <= price ) and not(following-sibling::order[contains(station_name, 'Jita')]/price < price))]` I think, that selects the element

```
<order id="4246442958">
  <region>10000002</region>
  <station>60003760</station>
  <station_name>Jita IV - Moon 4 - Caldari Navy Assembly Plant</station_name>
  <security>0.9</security>
  <range>65535</range>
  <price>10.00</price>
  <vol_remain>1</vol_remain>
  <min_volume>1</min_volume>
  <expires>2015-10-20</expires>
  <reported_time>09-20 07:48:23</reported_time>
</order>
```

Comment: Yes that worked! If I could upvote 10 times, I would. Thanks!